# String is given, get rid of duplicates and show frequency in hexadecimal instead

Tags: c, string, frequency

I need some assistance.

I have a string input, and I want to represent the repeated characters as hexadecimals.

Example input:

> ccccccccccfffffffffff ---> cAfB:
> where A = 10 repeats and B = 11 repeats

I have this working for characters in the hexadecimal, however my issue is what if the input is above 15, and the same characters.

Example input:

> bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
> ----> my code returns: b21:
> what i want: bFb6

Heres some code.

Notes: I had tried putting after the `++word_counter`, however it treats the above example as `b21`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){

  char words[100];
  char output_str[100];
  int i;
  char prev_word;
  int word_counter;
  word_counter = 1;

  scanf("%s",words);

  for (i=1; i<=strlen(words); ++i){
    prev_word = words[i-1];

    if (prev_word == words[i]){
      ++word_counter;
    if (word_counter == 15 || word_counter > 15){
      printf("%cF",prev_word);
      word_counter = 1;
        }
      if (word_counter == 14){
        printf("%cE", prev_word);
        word_counter = 1;
      }
    }
    else {
      if (word_counter == 1){
        printf("%c",prev_word); 
      }
      else {
        printf("%c%d",prev_word,word_counter);
        word_counter = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: *i want: b15b5*. Do you actually mean  `bFb5`?

Comment: *my code returns: b21*. I can't reproduce that. Either when I run it in my head and when I actually run it like [this](https://ideone.com/YUaADW). The result is `bEb7` which is still incorrect but closer to what you want. Suggest you use a debugger to step through your code to help you understand what it is doing.

Comment: You want bfb5 because 15 decimal  is 0xf.  I don't think you fully understand your class assignment

Comment: Your counter should reset to zero not one.  That's why you counted 21 instead of 20.

Comment: (word_counter == 15 || word_counter > 15) is the same as (word_counter >= 0xF)

Comment: Other mistakes aside, your code returns `bEb8`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the point of the assignment is to learn:

- hexadecimal format
- char processing
- maybe some bitwise operations

At any rate, you want to read the chars in one at a time instead of one big static string.  Detect when you get a new char.  Detect when the count is 0xF.  Detect the end of input.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    char current_c=0;
    char c=0;
    unsigned char count = 0;

    /* read one char at a time until we get a newline */
    while(c=getc(stdin)){

        if(0 == current_c){
            /* we got the first char */
            current_c = c;
            count++;
        }
        else if(c == current_c) {
            /* got a duplicate char */
            count++;
            if(count == 0xF){
                /* time for count to roll over */
                printf("%x%c", count, current_c);

                /* reset the counter */
                count = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (c=='\n') {
            /* we are at the end of the input */
            printf("%x%c", count, current_c);
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            /* We got a new char */

            if(count != 0) {
                printf("%x%c", count, current_c);
            }

            printf("%x%c", count, current_c);
            current_c = c;
            count=1;
        }

    }


    return 0;
}
```

output

```
$ ./main.exe
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccc
fb5bac
```

edge case where there are exactly 0xF b's followed by a new char. Given bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccc, we don't want fb0bac; we want fbac.

```
$ ./main.exe
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccc
fb5c
```